# I am using react and nodejs but it seems that I am having a problem in showing the interface in my browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using react and node.js but it seems that I am having a problem in showing the interface in my browser.

I have already changed the Switch to Routes because I am having an error and also instead of useHistory I changed it to useNavigate

App.js

```
      import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
  import ProductList from "./components/ProductList";
  import AddProduct from "./components/AddProduct";
  import EditProduct from "./components/EditProduct";
  
  function App() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="columns">
          <div className="column is-half is-offset-one-quarter">
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <ProductList />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/add">
                <AddProduct />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/edit/:id">
                <EditProduct />
              </Route>
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
  
  export default App;
```

ProductList.js

```
        import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
    import axios from "axios";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    
    const ProductList = () => {
        const [products, setProduct] = useState([]);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            getProducts();
        }, []);
    
        const getProducts = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/products');
            setProduct(response.data);
        }
    
        const deleteProduct = async (id) => {
            await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/products/${id}`);
            getProducts();
        }
    
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to="/add" className="button is-primary mt-2">Add New</Link>
                <table className="table is-striped is-fullwidth">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        { products.map((product, index) => (
                            <tr key={ product.id }>
                                <td>{ index + 1 }</td>
                                <td>{ product.title }</td>
                                <td>{ product.price }</td>
                                <td>
                                    <Link to={`/edit/${product.id}`} className="button is-small is-info">Edit</Link>
                                    <button onClick={ () => deleteProduct(product.id) } className="button is-small is-danger">Delete</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        )) }
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default ProductList
```

AddProduct.js

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const AddProduct = () => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const saveProduct = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/products',{
            title: title,
            price: price
        });
        navigate.push("/");
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={ saveProduct }>
                <div className="field">
                    <label className="label">Title</label>
                    <input 
                        className="input"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Title"
                        value={ title }
                        onChange={ (e) => setTitle(e.target.value) }
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="field">
                    <label className="label">Price</label>
                    <input 
                        className="input"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Price"
                        value={ price }
                        onChange={ (e) => setPrice(e.target.value) }
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="field">
                    <button className="button is-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddProduct
```

EditProduct.js

```
    /* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const EditProduct = () => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { id } = useParams();

    const updateProduct = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        await axios.patch(`http://localhost:5000/products/${id}`,{
            title: title,
            price: price
        });
        navigate.push("/");
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getProductById();
    }, []);

    const getProductById = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/products/${id}`);
        setTitle(response.data.title);
        setPrice(response.data.price);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={ updateProduct }>
                <div className="field">
                    <label className="label">Title</label>
                    <input 
                        className="input"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Title"
                        value={ title }
                        onChange={ (e) => setTitle(e.target.value) }
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="field">
                    <label className="label">Price</label>
                    <input 
                        className="input"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Price"
                        value={ price }
                        onChange={ (e) => setPrice(e.target.value) }
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="field">
                    <button className="button is-primary">Update</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default EditProduct
```

I am still new in using nodejs and react, and after editing the app.js it started not showing anything.